# Bootstrap List-Group on Fiddle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning `Bootstrap` and somehow it does not work on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/455cF/1/).

I copied a `list-group` example from the documentation provided by Twitter:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Import:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with the CDN you are trying to get the css from.  Try this:

```
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css');
```